# Why printf function behaving different to print float numbers in C?

Tags: c, floating-point

Why printf function acting different while printing floating values? sometimes it's using ceiling approach, sometimes floor. Let's have a look on the following code:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
        printf("10.10 = %.15lf\n", 10.10);
        printf("10.12 = %.15lf\n", 10.12);
        printf("10.15 = %.15lf\n", 10.15);
        return 0;
  }
```

```
The OUPUT is:
10.10 = 10.100000000000000
10.12 = 10.119999999999999
10.15 = 10.150000000000000
```

Can someone explain why it is printing floor value for 10.12 and why not for others?

Comment: `double` are encoded a 53-bit integer times some power-of-2.  `10.12` is not exactly encodable as such.  You are getting a close alternative.  Try `"%.18lf"` for all 3 to see more info.

Comment: "in case of 10.15 the the number upto the 15th decimal place would be 10.149999976158" --> How is that?  Please explain your thoughts as to why that value.

Comment: None of the decimal numbers convert exactly the format commonly used for `double`. Print them with `%.999g` and, if your C implementation is good, you will see the true values: 10.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375, 10.1199999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625, and 10.1500000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625.

Comment: There is no repetition after the decimal point in the case of 10.12, except there are a few finitely repeated digits here and there and then, after the last 5, there are infinitely many zeros.